# Is writing on NTFS partition from mac os considered safe now?

Tags: mac-osx, ntfs

I want to use my external USB hdd formatted as NTFS on my Mac and want full read/write previledge there. I know there are third party drivers to accomplish this (like [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/)) but I want to know how stable do you think to use such tools?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MacFuse runs very well here and I never had any problems leading to data loss - in fact I never had any problems to begin with.

There is one issue though: When a NTFS volume is not cleanly unmounted, NTFS-3g refuses to mount the disk in RW mode (it can be forced to do so though) and there are no tools available to clear that not-cleanly-unmounted flag from MacOS, which means that basically, you still need a Windows installation around.